# How do I add only arrowheads to an EPS gnuplot figure?

Tags: arrows, eps, gnuplot

As part of a diagram I want to add arrowheads indicating direction, but don't want the lines that normally come with them. Creating a very short line with an arrowhead is acceptable and works in gnuplot's wxt terminal, but the head shrinks to nothing when used with the epslatex terminal. How can I add arrowheads with no lines attached?

MWE:

```
reset
#set terminal wxt size 225,300
set terminal epslatex color size 2.25,3
set out "del3.tex"

set xrange[0:100]
set yrange[0:100]

set key off
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0

set style arrow 5 head filled size 7, 20, 60 lt -1#arrow with 1 head

set arrow from 20,50 to 80,50 as 5
set arrow from 20,30 to 21,30 as 5

plot x,x

set output#flush file output
exit
```

In this example file the second arrowhead is properly-sized when used with the wxt terminal (see commented line), but not when including the generated eps figure in latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There had been a feature request about this [#369 fixed size arrow head option](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/369/) and since 2013-08-09 the development version has an arrow option `fixed` to prevent this automatic shrinking:

```
set style arrow 5 head filled size 7, 20, 60 fixed lt -1
```

The other two options I see to workaround this with the current stable version is to either draw the arrow heads as polygons with `set object polygon ...`, or to use the terminal `lua tikz tikzarrows`. This does also ignore the arrow head shrinking, and you can use a tikz arrow style (the `angle` parameter is misued to specify an arrow style):

```
set style arrow 5 head size 1,2
```

to select the style `gp arrow 2`.

Comment: This appears to be added after the newest release version from April 2013. How can I obtain a gnuplot version with these additions? I'm using Windows7 x64.

Comment: @TomH57 You have the lastest stable release, I don't know if the next patchlevel will include this feature. From time to time snapshot binaries are provided for the development version on http://www.gnuplot.info/development/binaries/, but the current snapshot does not include the `fixed` option for arrows. And I've never compiled gnuplot on Windows, sorry.

Comment: Was able to use the current gnuplot version arrows by making them just long enough and hiding the tails behind adjacent objects. Your answer using "fixed" should be the preferred method for future gnuplot versions, so I'm marking it as the answer.